# In any IntelliJ IDE debugging interface, how to add a watch with multiple lines of code?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, watch

In any of these IDE, there are only 2 options in a debugging session (after breaking at a breakpoint):

1. watch a variable/expression that contains a single line
2. evaluate an expression that may contains multiple line

The evaluate expression however are lost after I close the window, this is very annoying and inefficient, how to combine these 2 features and create a watch that executes multiple lines?

Answer (score 1):

You can chain expresions in variable/expression with `;`. It will show the last expression's result. You can even define variables like   `int x  = 5; int result = x*somethingFromYourCode;` it will show the result variable value.